# When vue-router passes parameters, how to solve the duplicate id and route name?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When vue-router passes parameters in the form of "path: "/user/:id"/", how can other routes be redirected normally?
for example

user/4089838987906461

user/settings/profile

In this case, the intermediate settings will be judged as values

How to achieve it through configuration

Comment: if you have a defined router path `path: '/user/settings/profile'`, it will not be confused for a path that uses less segments such as `/user/:id`